# How can I effectively debug C code that's wrapped with JNI in Eclipse? (Android Dev)

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I've got a segfault but I have absolutely no idea how to locate it.

Tips?
[image]

Comment: I tried following this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902066/how-to-call-java-methods-from-c-in-jni/3902495#3902495 but I'm segfaulting before I even get a chance to make a call to logcat :/

Comment: Private variables cannot be passed to the native function. D'oh.

Comment: Easy & not so quick way: Try isolating the calls in your native layer in a step by step manner and check which call is going wrong. Also, worth trying is : <ndk>/docs/NDK-GDB.HTML — describes how to use the native code debugger

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the location of the C function that caused the crash using the [Android NDK Stacktrace Analyzer](http://code.google.com/p/android-ndk-stacktrace-analyzer/).

The steps are on [the wiki](http://code.google.com/p/android-ndk-stacktrace-analyzer/wiki/Usage), but basically you need to get the stack trace from logcat into a file (`adb logcat > mycrash.log`), then dump your library to a text file, then run the program on the two of them. Here's the shell script I use to do the lot:

```
#!/bin/sh
if test $# -lt 2 ; then
    echo "Extract readable stack trace from Android logcat crash"
    echo "Usage $0 lib.so crash.log"
    exit 1
fi
of=$(mktemp)
echo "Disassemble $1"
~/tools/android-ndk-r5/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-objdump -S $1 > $of
echo "Parse stack trace in $2"
~/bin/parse_stack.py $of $2
```

Change the paths to the Android NDK and parse_stack.py file as you need.

Comment: So glad to finally find something like this. I was tired of going through the gdbserver rigmarole just to get a trace from a segfault.

Comment: I just submitted a patch to the project that shows the code segment where the crash occurred as well: http://code.google.com/p/android-ndk-stacktrace-analyzer/issues/detail?id=1

Comment: Are you following me Jason LeBrun? Haha. Thanks richq. That's awesome.

Answer (score 6):

How to Effectively Debug Android JNI C/C++ Code in Eclipse:

1. Setup your project to be a mixed Java, C, and C++ project:

   http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-development/
2. Setup your project to enable debugging:

   http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-debugging/#more-23

Note: The author of the site used Eclipse(Galileo) on Ubuntu.  I found some differences when
using Eclipse(Helios) on MacOS (especially with the debug setup).  Once things are set up, Eclipse works very well as an IDE for JNI development.

Comment: Okay can they make that more difficult to setup?  I still can't get it to work for debugging.