# Can I call `Log.*` within my C code? I want to debug using LogCat

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, logcat

I am stuck and am getting an error somewhere within my C code, and I do not know where. I would like to use the simple `Log.i( tag, msg )` or `Log.e( tag, msg )` commands. I have looked around online and have found two other questions on SO but neither of them deal with exactly what I'm saying.

[This method is not what I'm looking for...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846080/how-can-i-effectively-debug-c-code-thats-wrapped-with-jni-in-eclipse-android)

[And this is exactly what I'm looking for, but in C++, not C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3902495/1435712)

If the syntax in C++/C is the same, I'm sorry but I have little experience in both.

Comment: Have you tried option #2 in the second question you linked? Seems like by far the simplest option. `adb shell setprop log.redirect-stdio true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax in C is the same

```
#include <android/log.h>

#define TAG "MYDEBUG"

#ifdef DEBUG
#  define  D(x...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG , x)
#else
#  define  D(x...) do {} while (0)
#endif

#  define  W(x...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, TAG , x)
#  define  E(x...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, TAG , x)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <cutils/log.h>
#define LOG_TAG "MYDEBUG"

...
ALOGD("Here we are!");
```

In older releases the macro was:

```
LOGD("Here we are!");
```

Comment: Where is this log file? I was also wondering the difference between ALOGD, ALOGE and ALOGI...

Comment: @ChefPharaoh ./system/core/include/cutils/log.h

Comment: I more meant where is this log file being kept or stored. But I figured out I can just use logcat with various arguments to see the log I desire. Although still would be nice to know where these log files live.

Comment: @ChefPharaoh The logs are not stored in files on the file system. Android documentation says "Logs from various applications and portions of the system are collected in a series of circular buffers"